MNIST and SVM classification problem with a custom test data
By training the model on this dataset I obtain a high accuracy. Around 95%, which is good. Especially using ‘rbf’ as the kernel. However, when using images made by me, the prediction is really very bad. I don't know if this is because SVM is not able to detect complex behaviours or if I am making a mistake when converting my image to MNIST.
# Carga del dataset MNIST
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# Normalización de los píxeles
X_train = X_train / 255.0
X_test = X_test / 255.0

# Aplanamiento de las imágenes
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 784)
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1, 784)

# Creación y entrenamiento del modelo SVM
model = SVC(kernel='linear')
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicciones en el conjunto de prueba
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# Evaluación del modelo
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print("Precisión:", accuracy)
print("Matriz de confusión:\n", conf_matrix)

To convert the images to MNIST I use:
from PIL import ImageEnhance

def loadImage(image_path):
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    #plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
    #plt.title('Imagen Original')
    #plt.imshow(img)
    #plt.axis('off')
    #plt.show()
    return img

def redToWhite(img):
    img = img.convert("RGB")  # Convertir a formato RGB
    data = img.getdata()  # Obtener los datos de los píxeles
    newData = []  # Lista para almacenar los nuevos datos de la imagen

    for item in data:
        red, green, blue = item
        
        # Definir el rango de tonalidades vinotinto
        if red >= 60 and red <= 136 and green == 0 and blue <= 21:
            # Si el color está en el rango de vinotinto, lo cambiamos a blanco
            newData.append((255, 255, 255))
        else:
            # Mantener el color original si no es vinotinto
            newData.append(item)

    img.putdata(newData)  # Aplicar los nuevos datos a la imagen
    img.save('/content/redToWhite.png')  # Guardar la nueva imagen
    return img  # Devolver la imagen procesada


def greyScale(img):
    greyImg = img.convert('L')
    greyImg.save('/content/grey.png')
    #plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    #plt.axis('off')
    #plt.show()
    return greyImg

def invertColor(img):
    # Solo aplicar inversión si la imagen es en escala de grises
    if img.mode == 'L':
        invertedImg = ImageOps.invert(img)
        invertedImg.save('/content/inverted.png')
        return invertedImg
    else:
        raise ValueError("La imagen no está en escala de grises")

def smooth(img):
    img = img.filter(ImageFilter.SMOOTH)
    img.save('/content/smooth.png')
    return img

def resize(img):
    img = img.resize((28, 28))
    #plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    #plt.axis('off')
    #plt.show()
    # Guardar la imagen
    img.save('/content/resize.png')
    return img

def finalWhite(img):
  img = img.convert("RGB")
  data = img.getdata()
  newData = []
  for item in data:
    if item[0] != 0 and item[1] != 0  and item[2] != 0:
      newData.append((255, 255, 255))
    else:
      newData.append(item)
  img.putdata(newData)
  imgArray = np.array(img)
  print("Shape del array después de finalWhite:", imgArray.shape)  # Esto debería ser (28, 28, 4)
  img.save('/content/finalWhite.png')
  return img

def contrast(img, factor):
    enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(img)
    img = enhancer.enhance(factor)
    img.save('/content/contrast.png')
    return img

def normalizeImg(img):
    imgArray = np.array(img)
    imgArray = imgArray / 255.0
    imgArray = imgArray.reshape(1, 784)
    return imgArray

def borders(img, thickness):
  # Invertir la imagen para que el dígito sea blanco y el fondo negro
  img = ImageOps.invert(img)
  # Aplicar dilatación para engrosar el dígito
  img = img.filter(ImageFilter.MaxFilter(thickness))
  # Volver a invertir la imagen para que el dígito sea negro y el fondo blanco
  img = ImageOps.invert(img)
  return img

def predict_digit(img):
    #img = blackToWhite(img)
    img = redToWhite(img)
    img = borders(img, 5)
    img = greyScale(img)
    img = invertColor(img)
    img = resize(img)
    img = contrast(img,10)
    imgArray = normalizeImg(img)
    # Predecir el dígito
    prediction = log_reg_model.predict(imgArray)
    return prediction[0]

# Opcional: Visualizar algunas predicciones
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 10, figsize=(10, 3))
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.imshow(X_test[i+100].reshape(28, 28), cmap='gray')
    ax.set_title(f'Pred: {y_pred[i+100]}')
    ax.axis('off')
plt.show()

# Usar la función para predecir una imagen específica
#img = loadImage('/content/6test.png')  # Cambia esto por la ruta de tu imagen
#predicted_digit = predict_digit(img)
#print(f'El dígito predicho para la imagen es: {predicted_digit}')
for i in range(50):
  img = loadImage(f'/content/{i+1}.png')  # Cambia esto por la ruta de tu imagen
  predicted_digit = predict_digit(img)
  print(f'El dígito predicho para la imagen es: {predicted_digit}, imagen numero {i+1}')

I made this code this way because my sample images are similar to these:

Finally, my question is: Is it normal for this to happen because by taking these images to a MNIST-like format a lot of information is lost or am I doing something wrong?

Hi, please provide your imports in the code. For instance, what are Image, ImageOps, and ImageFilter? Where do they come from?
Also, my first thought is that somehow the final outputs of the image conversion may be in a somewhat different distribution somehow. Maybe look at what the images look like after you reformat them and check whether they look like MNIST images.
